# Скрипт блокирует событие :checked у инпута

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице есть кастомные инпуты-чекбоксы и дропдауны, для последних написан код, позволяющий закрывать их по клику вне их области, но из-за него не работает :checked у инпутов. Как исправить скрипт, чтобы все осталось работоспособным?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".header__dropdown-link").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    fnCloseAllDropdown(ev.target.nextElementSibling);
    ev.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("painting-style__dropdown_show");
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.closest(".painting-style__dropdown_show")) return;
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropagation();
  fnCloseAllDropdown();
});

function fnCloseAllDropdown(obj) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".painting-style__dropdown").forEach(el => {
    if (el != obj) {
      el.classList.remove("painting-style__dropdown_show");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.list-reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


.publications__label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.publications__input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.publications__span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.publications__span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.publications__span::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #c283f3;
  opacity: 0;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__span {
  color: red;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__span::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.publications__input:focus+.publications__span {
  outline: 3px solid red;
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<h3 class="publications__left-column-subheading white-font">Категории</h3>
<ul class="list-reset publications__list-categories">
  <li class="publications__list-item">
    <label class="publications__label prime-text white-font">
       <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" />
       <span class="publications__span prime-text white-font">Бестселлеры</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="publications__list-item">
    <label class="publications__label prime-text white-font">
       <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" />
       <span class="publications__span prime-text white-font">Искусство</span>
     </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ev.preventDefault(); ev.stopPropagation();` - так до инпута же событие `click` не доходит, каким образом ему `:checked` изменять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла построчная отладка этого кода:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".header__dropdown-link").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    fnCloseAllDropdown(ev.target.nextElementSibling);
    ev.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("painting-style__dropdown_show");
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.closest(".painting-style__dropdown_show")) return;
  ev.preventDefault();//проблема была здесь, удалив эту строку, все заработало
  ev.stopPropagation();
  fnCloseAllDropdown();
});

function fnCloseAllDropdown(obj) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".painting-style__dropdown").forEach(el => {
    if (el != obj) {
      el.classList.remove("painting-style__dropdown_show");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваши скрипты никоем образом не влияют на чекбоксы. Ваша проблема что span накрывает input(видно на изображении) и вы не может епо нему кликнуть, просто добавьте z-index для скрытых input
Еще бы неплохо было бы их выровнять

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".header__dropdown-link").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    fnCloseAllDropdown(ev.target.nextElementSibling);
    ev.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("painting-style__dropdown_show");
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.closest(".painting-style__dropdown_show")) return;
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropagation();
  fnCloseAllDropdown();
});

function fnCloseAllDropdown(obj) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".painting-style__dropdown").forEach(el => {
    if (el != obj) {
      el.classList.remove("painting-style__dropdown_show");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.list-reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


.publications__label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.publications__input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.publications__span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.publications__span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.publications__span::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #c283f3;
  opacity: 0;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__span {
  color: red;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__span::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.publications__input:focus+.publications__span {
  outline: 3px solid red;
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<h3 class="publications__left-column-subheading white-font">Категории</h3>
<ul class="list-reset publications__list-categories">
  <li class="publications__list-item">
    <label class="publications__label prime-text white-font">
       <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" />
       <span class="publications__span prime-text white-font">Бестселлеры</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="publications__list-item">
    <label class="publications__label prime-text white-font">
       <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" />
       <span class="publications__span prime-text white-font">Искусство</span>
     </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: там должна появиться фиолетовая точка на :сhecked, у вас так и не появилась. Для z-index не обязательно абсолют, подойдет и relative. Дело было в этом -ev.preventDefault(); в средней части скрипта, убрал и заработало)